# Why is catch IOException needed in this situation

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

I saw this example of using `FileInuputStream` and `FileOutputStream`:

```
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./TestDir/IOfile.txt");
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./TestDir/IOfile_out.txt")) {

    // Do something...

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I omitted the part that says `// Do something...`, because this issue will happen even if all those operations are gone.

Since the constructor of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` may throw out `FileNotFoundException`, I can understand why catching the `FileNotFoundException`.

But what is the base for catching `IOException`? It seems that the compiler won't let it work without it, and I don't know how I could know that this is needed.

Comment: the `close` method, which is called by `a try-with-resources` can throw an IOException

Comment: You don't just read a file, you `write()` a different one. Writing may cause an `IOException`, maybe in case you don't have write access on the path. See [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html): `write(...) throws IOException`. By the way, @CarlosHeuberger is right, too.

Comment: Yet there is no need to catch `FileNotFoundException` since you already catch `IOException`

Comment: @deHaar   But there is no `close()` method written in this block. Is it because I used try () {} as try-with-resource way of coding, so there is a implicitly hidden `close()`?

Comment: I haven't written anything about the close method... But it is implicitly used by try with resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is coming from the `close()` method, if you see the method signature of `close()` in `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`:

```
public void close() throws IOException
```

It has a throws clause for the checked exception `IOException`, so you need to handle it.
Also since you are using a try-with-resources block this is not obvious as you are not explicitly closing it.

The resources opened in the `try` block are closed automatically by invoking the `close` method when exiting it, provided the resources are implementing the interface `AutoCloseble`, otherwise you can't use them in try-with-resources.

If you don't invoke the `close()` (which is bad) method on the `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`, then you don't need to handle the `IOException`, the following will compile fine :

```
 try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./TestDir/IOfile.txt");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./TestDir/IOfile_out.txt");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        // more operations
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then if you close the resources properly, in the finally block:

```
 try {
        in = new FileInputStream("./TestDir/IOfile.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("./TestDir/IOfile_out.txt");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        // more operations
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            if(in!=null && out!= null) {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You would need to handle it.

Comment: But there is no `close()` method written in this block. Is it because I used try () {} as try-with-resource way of coding, so there is a implicitly hidden `close()`?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 in try-with-resources the resources are opened in the try block and the resources are closed automatically by calling the close method, so that you don't forget to do it. `close()` method of Objects implementing `AutoCloseble` are called automatically when the `try` block is exited.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are catching `FileNotFoundException` does not mean it can not throw an `IOException`.

Scenario 1: File not found => FileNotFoundException
Scenario 2: File found / operations done, but closing failed => IOException

Since you are using the [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) with the `FileInputStream` which implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) it will call [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--)  right after the following lines are terminated or thrown out by an exception.

Comment: I see. try-with-resources statement does include an implicit `close()`.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Exactly like that.